# Llamar a función livewire desde rutas web - Laravel

Tags: laravel, livewire

Se necesita llamar a una función incrustada en el controlador livewire desde el manejador de rutas web laravel.

Anteriormente para llamar a una funcion desde los controladores laravel lo hacia desde la siguiente manera

```
Route::get('/name', 'NameController@NameFunction');
```

Pero a hora necesito llamar a una funcion desde un controlador livewire y no logro saber cual es la manera correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo tuve el mismo problemas, mi clase se llama 'create.php', espero esto te ayude:

```
Route::get('/productos', [Livewire\Product\create::class]);
```

Tenía al componente Livewire en la carpeta Livewire dentro de otra carpeta llamada Product, en tu caso solo sería Livewire\create:class

Answer (score 2):

Cuando renderizas una vista con Livewire, la presentación de ésta se vuelve stateful y pasa a ser controlada por el componente que invocó `render`. La vista puede seguir interactuando con la clase del componente invocando métodos públicos que éste disponibilice.

Si tu controller fuese:

```
class ExampleComponent extends \Livewire\Component {

    public $message='';
    public function mount(Request $request) {
       // acá puedes usar el request para computar
       // el estado inicial...
    }

    public function render() {
       return view('livewire.example');
    }

    public function updateMessage() {
        $this->message = 'Actualizado en timestamp: '. time();
    }
}
```

Y la vista tuviera en un lugar

```
   <button wire:click="updateMessage">actualizar</button>
   <span>{{ $message }} </span>
```

Al presionar el botón se invocaría al método `updateMessage`, sin que tú tengas que gatillar un request via ajax o fetch ni procesar la respuesta de éste.

La invocación de este método a su vez actualizará la propiedad pública `$message`, y con ello se refrescará el segmento de la vista.

Si bien tanto la invocación del método como el refresco del contenido se manejan internamente con llamadas ajax, éstas son internas a Livewire y ajenas a tu control.

El único request tradicional que el componente llega a conocer es el que recibe originalmente en el método `mount`, que sería análogo a lo que el método `__construct` recibe en un componente tradicional de Blade.

Answer (score 1):

En laravel livewire las rutas direccionan hacia [componentes](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/making-components). Luego, cada componente ejecuta su método `render()`.

Por ejemplo, la ruta a continuación `/post` dirige hacia el componente llamado `Posts` la cual ejecutará su método `render`.

```
Route::get('/post', Posts::class);
```

---

**Posts.php**

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.show-posts');
}

// Puedes agregar más métodos

public function destroy($id)
{
    ....
}
```

Dado que se ejecuta el método render, lo que obtendras es que al dirigirte a la ruta `/post` serás redirigido hacia la vista llamada `livewire.show-posts`.

Posterior a ello, en dicha vista puedes llamar a otros métodos dentro de su componente, como por ejemplo el método **destroy**. Puedes leer acerca de ello [aquí](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions).

Comment: Eso lo tengo entenido, pero necesito llamar a la función mediante la ruta no mediante componente , como anteriormente lo hacia con los controladores. La solucion que encuentro es crear un método render por separado pero quería saber si es posible hacerlo mediante rutas

Comment: Hasta ahora no explicas bien lo que deseas. Plantea un ejemplo de lo quieres obtener. Algo como "Estoy en mi vista principal, y al presionar un botón quiero que pase esto", para poder entender lo que realmente quieres.  Así como lo dices, es ambiguo entender lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Por el momento la respuesta que veo es crear un componente especifico para esa ruta (= me parece mala esta solucion porque tendriamos cientos de componentes haciendo una funcion especifica aunque ese puede ser su principio)
En fin, en mi caso tengo un modelo actividad, el cual lo gestiono con un usuario administrador, pero con otro usuario participante quiero entrar a ella y realizar un conjunto de acciones, esta claro que aqui el Modelo es el mismo pero las acciones son diferentes, redactando esto se me ocurre controlar el acceso a partes de las vistas mediante el clasico @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin) y asi resuelvo el tema de tener mas de un componente apuntado al mismo Modelo, o sea, se puede jugar con las variables globales tambien.

Comment: revisen el siguiente enlace tambien  https://styde.net/mover-logica-de-un-controlador-a-un-componente-de-laravel-livewire/